# ImportError: No module named node_example.msg

Tags: ros, add-message-files

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package named node_exemple containing an msg folder containing these files

ViewTemplate.msg
To run a python file depending on this message I used :

```
from node example.msg  import ViewTemplate
```

But I get this error :

```
from node_example.msg import ViewTemplate   
ImportError: No module named node_example.msg
```

The CMakeLists.txt is here :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3) 
project(node_example)
    
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
  dynamic_reconfigure 
  message_generation 
  roscpp 
  rosgraph_msgs 
  nav_msgs 
  rospy 
  std_msgs
)

add_message_files(FILES 
  NodeExampleData.msg 
  TopologicalAction.msg 
  TopologicalEdge.msg 
  TopologicalMap.msg 
  TopologicalNode.msg 
  ViewTemplate.msg 
)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES 
  geometry_msgs
  std_msgs
)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/nodeExample.cfg)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS 
  dynamic_reconfigure 
  message_runtime 
  roscpp 
  rosgraph_msgs
  rospy
  std_msgs
  visualization_msgs 
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

install(PROGRAMS 
  src/main_lv.py
  src/pylistener.py
  src/pytalker.py
  src/ratslam/posecell_network.py
  src/ratslam/experience_map_younes.py 
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(PROGRAMS 
  src/main_lv.py
  src/main_em.py
  src/pytalker.py
  src/ratslam/posecell_network.py
  src/ratslam/experience_map_younes.py
  src/ratslam/local_view_match.py
 DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270324/importerror:-no-module-named-node_example.msg/) by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-06**:
Can you post your `CMakeLists.txt`? Also, is the message in a directory called `msg`?

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-09-07**:
Yes I put the message in a directory called msg

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-07**:
@Younès: please update your *question* with new information instead of posting a new *answer*. I updated your question with the info from the answer that you posted (and formatted it). Please delete the answer that you posted. Thanks.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-07**:
http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-09-07**:
thank you ok

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2017-09-07**:
Did you run `catkin_make` prior to trying to run the node? You will need to do that to have the messages be generated.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-07**:
@Younès: just as an aside, you should look at this tutorial on [using a `Makefile` with Python](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

There are quite a few things that can go wrong when creating a custom message. By the error you are showing, and assuming that you didn't forget to compile your workspace, I woud say that maybe you've missed to do the source.

> source devel/setup.bash

By the way, I've created a video showing the steps you should do when you create a custom a message, by reproducing a case based on yours. The steps the video covers are:

1. Create the package containing the Message file.
2. Modify the CMakeLists.txt file
3. Modify the package.xml file
4. Compile and source your workspace
5. Use the new message in a Python Script

Here you have the video in case you want to have a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPmlFNb7v4Y

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Alberto E.](https://answers.ros.org/users/31003/alberto-e./) with karma: 356 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-12**:
There is not information here to be a complete answer. Modify the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml how? Use the new message how? Please include *all* of the relevant information (i.e., what to change and the script that you're referring to).

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-09-12**:
Thank you. It works.

**Comment by [Alberto E.](https://answers.ros.org/users/31003/alberto-e./) on 2017-09-12**:
@Younès You're welcome! Glad to help.